# ActiveRecord override has_many relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

So i'm trying to override a relation `has_many` in a rails 4.2 application.

I've a model `Event` who `has_many :picturables`.

The `Event` can also `has_one :contact` and this `Contact` also `has_many :picturables`.

What I try to achieve is that when we call `event.picturables`, is returns the `picturables` for the `Event` and also those of the `Contact`.

I've tried to do this with the 'extend association' :

```
has_many :picturables, ->{ order(:position) }, as: :picturable, class_name: "Picturable", dependent: :delete_all do
  def <missing_name>
    event = proxy_association.owner
    event.contact.present? ? event.picturables + event.contact.picturables : event.picturables
  end
  def poney
    event = proxy_association.owner
    event.contact.present? ? event.picturables + event.contact.picturables : event.picturables
  end
end
```

So when I do `event.picturables.poney` it works like I want.However, I'd like to override the `event.picturables` directly.

I tried to name the method `self` or `itself` but it doesn't work.

Is what i want to achieve possible the way I tried, or do I instead need to declare a 'normal' method?

Can you guys help me?

Thanks in advance

Edit :

The solution i choose :

I wasn't able to find the solution the way i search, so i implemented an other idea :

```
  def picturables
    unless contact.nil?
      Picturable.where('(picturable_id = ? AND picturable_type = ?) OR (picturable_id = ? AND picturable_type = ?)', id, 'Event', contact.id, 'Contact')
    else
      super
    end
  end

  def pictures
    Picture.where(id: picturables.map(&:picture_id))
  end
```

The advantage of making a 'where' by hand is that we still have a ActiveRecord:RelationProxy as return, because when i made event.picturables + event.contact.picturables it's return an array

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "I tried to name the method `self` or `itself` but it doesn't work"? Are you talking about the `<missing_name>` method? I would imagine you can simply override `def self.picturables` in the `Event` class, with the logic you're already using?...

Comment: Your guess right, i try to replace <missing_name> by self or itself and it doesn't work.
I try to override the picturables in the event class, and it's work when we call event.picturables, but when we call event.pictures, we don't have the pictures from the contact (Picturable is a table used for the many-to-many relation)